next-image-unconfigured-host error after setting hostname with wildcards
I'm running a google image search that returns the links for images from everywhere on the internet. I have set my nextConfig to use wildcards because I cannot manually add all these hostnames. The issue is even after including the wildcards, the unconfigured-host error continues to show.
I'm using NextJS 14.2.0
const nextConfig = {
  images: {
    formats: ["image/avif", "image/webp"],
    remotePatterns: [
      {
        protocol: "https",
        hostname: "**",
      },
      {
        protocol: "http",
        hostname: "localhost:3000",
      },
    ]

The only way I have found to go around this is to include "unoptimized" as part of the Image component. This avoid the page from crashing, but I hope someone can provide a better solution
<Image
  unoptimized
  key={index}
  src={video.imageUrl}
  width={1000}
  height={1000}
  alt={`Thumbnail ${index + 1}`}
  className="w-20 h-20 object-cover cursor-pointer"
  onClick={() => handleThumbnailClick(video.link)}
  />

